# Problemas com importação do WSDL da nfe

Tags: java, web-service, nfe, wsdl

Estou com um erro que não consigo descobrir o que é. Peguei o SWDL de NfeAutorizacao (homologação) e usei o Axis2 para gerar as classes. Resolvi alguns problemas de importação e de lib, porém ocorre alguns problemas ainda.

Trecho do código onde da o erro:

```
  org.apache.axiom.om.OMDataSource dataSource =new org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBDataSource(this,MY_QNAME);
           return factory.createOMElement(dataSource,MY_QNAME);
```

Erro da primeira linha:

> Cannot instantiate the type ADBDataSource.

Erro da segunda  linha:

> The method createOMElement(QName, OMContainer) in the type OMFactory
>   is not applicable for the arguments (OMDataSource, QName).

Se eu fiz a geração de acordo com os WSDL, ele não deveria ter esse tipo de problema, certo?

Comment: Pelo erro descrito, talvez seja os argumentos passados para o método que não estejam corretos (eu não posso ter certeza), porém não tem como saber se você não disser da onde vem as variáveis `this`, `MY_QNAME` e `dataSource` e de tipo elas são, poste um exemplo do código que possa ser reproduzido para gerar o erro.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Acabei resolvendo de uma maneira estranha. Quando tinha o erro, eu tinha gerado as classes com a versão mais nova do axis, depois, peguei uma versão um pouco mais antiga, gerei elas novamente, e acabou resolvendo. Não faço a mínima ideia porque resolveu sendo que a geração foi feita da mesma forma, apenas com uma versão mais antiga.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu, poderia informar algo mais sobre as classes geradas? Principalmente colocar na pergunta todas se possível (não precisa ser o seu projeto, de preferência tente reproduzir o seu problema em uma versão mais simples) e adicione a sua questão (editando ela) e forneça a versão do Axi e ou outro qualquer ferramenta que você usou para gerar.

Answer (score 2):

A geração de arquivos para comunicação realmente é bem custosa e propensa a erros.

Aqui na empresa onde trabalho, tivemos muitos problemas com as classes geradas pelo axis, a ponto de mantermos apenas os stubs gerados e reimplementamos o mapeamento todo. Se você olhar as classes geradas, verá que existe muito lixo, duplicações e outros "bad smells" no codigo que, em alguns casos, podem gerar problemas. Aqui tivemos problemas com os namespaces em alguns casos e, como as classes era geradas, ficava dificil altera-las.

As classes que implementamos funcionavam muito bem na versão 2.0 e, quando migramos pra 3.10, tentamos achar algo na internet que estivesse bem testado e que fosse confiável para usarmos aqui e não achamos. Então, acabamos liberando nossa própria implementação, após a adaptação para a NFe 3.10. Ela atualmente se encontra em https://github.com/wmixvideo/nfe, se tiveres interesse.

[]s